# Is the operating system responsible for booting up of the computer?

Tags: function, operating-system

I wanted to know if the operating system is responsible for booting up of the computer or not? And if yes, how?

What are the tasks performed?

Thanks

Comment: The OS sits on your storage and is called after BIOS checks are complete.  So when you power on your machine, BIOS checks are performed, and Booting is initialized if your machine is configured properly. So it depends on what you mean by "booting"

Comment: I think this should be migrated to Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: No

Longer Answer:
    While your operating system is responsible for a portion of start up, called the OS initiation, it is not responsible for the booting of the computer.  The booting is done by the BIOS, which usually comes pre-installed on the computer. All the operating system does is operate the computer, not boot or start up.

[Tutorial on BIOS](http://www.7tutorials.com/simple-questions-what-bios-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 2):

The BIOS is responsible for starting up the computer proper, and for then bootstrapping into the actual Operating System. More on what the BIOS is [**here**](http://www.7tutorials.com/simple-questions-what-bios-what-does-it-do).